# Multiple event handlers in .change() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pretty simple syntax question.

Can I have more one event handler in a change function (or other functions, while I'm at it)?

So something like this:

```
$("#ctlPerson").change(function() {
```

to something like this

```
$("#ctlPerson", "#ctlPerson2", "#ctlPerson3" ).change(function() {
```

**EDIT:**

Ok you guys seem to think this works. But it doesn't.

If I were to have

```
$("#ctlPerson").change(function() {
```

and

```
$("#ctlPerson2").change(function() {
```

these would both would. However, this:

```
$("#ctlPerson", "#ctlPerson2").change(function() {
```

does not work for me

Comment: Why don't you try it and let us know? ;-)

Comment: Yes. Yes you can. Just like you would in a stylesheet.

Comment: my syntax doesn't work, that's for sure

Comment: $("#ctlPerson", "#ctlPerson2") is wrong. $("#ctlPerson, #ctlPerson2") is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as separate strings. [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) doesn't use multiple arguments in that manner.

But, a single string can use the [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#ctlPerson, #ctlPerson2, #ctlPerson3").change(function() { ... });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XNY7E/

---

Though, you might consider assigning common `class` names to each element and using a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
<select id="ctlPerson" class="ctlPeople"></select>
<select id="ctlPerson2" class="ctlPeople"></select>
<select id="ctlPerson3" class="ctlPeople"></select>
```

```
$('.ctlPeople').change(function () { ... });
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Would having #ctlPerson in another .change method affect it?

Comment: This is a solid SO answer.

Comment: @FelixMaxime No, multiple handlers shouldn't inherently conflict with each other. Are `.off('change')` or `.unbind('change')` being used anywhere? Do the elements exist at the time the selector attempts to find them (`$('#ctlPerson, #ctlPerson2, #ctlPerson3').length === 3`)? Are they dynamic with the potential to be replaced by very similarly-looking elements?

Comment: Ok take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Fm87a/
if I were to add ctlLevel to $("#ctlPerson").change(function()
it would break the code.
However, if I were to create the exact same method with ctlLevel instead of ctlPerson, it would work fine. I mean, I could, but I'm really wondering why I can just put them in the same function.

Comment: @FelixMaxime Using `$("#ctlPerson, #ctlLevel").change(...)` should alter `You are:` when `Niveau` is changed as I'd assumed you're expecting, http://jsfiddle.net/V2f9F/. Can you include another fiddle with what you tried for "*if I were to add ctlLevel to $("#ctlPerson").change(function() it would break the code*?" Or, elaborate on what you mean by "*not working*?" What does it do? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: OKAY I FINALLY UNDERSTOOD.

I was writing $("#ctlPerson", "#ctlLevel") when I needed to write $("#ctlPerson, #ctlLevel"). So yeah I'm blind and retarded ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ctlPerson, #ctlPerson2, #ctlPerson3" ).change();
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/